# how to save image automatically when plot images in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, hook

I want to save the plot automatically every times. I know in general we can do this as follows:

```r
png("filename.png")
plot(1:5)
dev.off()
```

However, I don't want that, but like this shown as follows:

```r
plot(1:6)
plot(1:7)
```

every time I call plot, it will save the plot automatically, I also know that there are two hook functions: `before.plot.new` and `plot.new`, If I set the hook on `before.plot.new` as follows, it can save the picture when I plot the next image, but this is not what I want, we need save the image every time I plot it.

```r
my_function <- function(){
  print("function")
  filepath <- tempfile(tmpdir = getwd(), fileext = ".svg")
  temp <- dev.list()
  print(temp)
  dev.copy(svglite, file=filepath)
  temp <- dev.cur()
  print(temp)
  dev.off()
  temp <- dev.list()
  print(temp)
  print("exit")
}
setHook('before.plot.new', my_function, action = "prepend")
```

If I set the hook on `plot.new` as follows, it can save a picture when I plot the image, but the content of file is empty, the reason may be that the device start a new frame.

```r
setHook('plot.new', my_function, action = "append")
```

So how can save a image when plot it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use ggplot2, then the [camcorder](https://github.com/thebioengineer/camcorder) package allows you to save plots automatically each time you run the plotting code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems that this package overrides the print function in ggplot.